# ntpd error: unable to bind to wildcard address 0.0.0.0 - another process may be running - EXITING

Tags: centos, iptables, ntpd

I have a problem.
Time on server not synchronized.
And it seems that this problem was appear after I set my rules for iptables, which I described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/693561/iptables-drops-all-but-postfix-still-send-emails) May be I'm wrong and these two events are not related...

CentOS 7.1
ntpd 4.2.6p5

*/var/log/messages*

```
May 25 16:48:49 CentOS-70-64-minimal ntpd[26771]: ntpd 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Sat Dec 20 02:38:09 UTC 2014 (1)
May 25 16:48:49 CentOS-70-64-minimal ntpd[26771]: proto: precision = 0.046 usec
May 25 16:48:49 CentOS-70-64-minimal ntpd[26771]: 0.0.0.0 c01d 0d kern kernel time sync enabled
May 25 16:48:49 CentOS-70-64-minimal ntpd[26771]: unable to bind to wildcard address 0.0.0.0 - another process may be running - EXITING
```

*ntp.conf*

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
restrict default nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1 
restrict ::1
includefile /etc/ntp/crypto/pw
keys /etc/ntp/keys
disable monitor
server ntp1.hetzner.de iburst
server ntp2.hetzner.com iburst
server ntp3.hetzner.net iburst
```

**EDIT**
*netstat -lanp | grep ':123'*

```
udp        0      0 5.9.152.9:123           0.0.0.0:*                           24483/ntpd          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                           24483/ntpd          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           24483/ntpd          
udp6       0      0 2a01:4f8:190:4008:::123 :::*                                24483/ntpd          
udp6       0      0 fe80::3285:a9ff:fee:123 :::*                                24483/ntpd          
udp6       0      0 ::1:123                 :::*                                24483/ntpd          
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                                24483/ntpd
```

**EDIT 2**

This problem became more shadow for me...

*service ntpd status*

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  ntpd.service
ntpd.service - Network Time Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ntpd.service; disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

*systemctl list-unit-files | grep 'ntp'*

```
ntpd.service                            disabled
ntpdate.service                         disabled
```

*netstat -nlap | grep 'ntpd'*

```
udp        0      0 5.9.152.9:123           0.0.0.0:*                           3588/ntpd           
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                           3588/ntpd           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           3588/ntpd           
udp6       0      0 2a01:4f8:190:4008:::123 :::*                                3588/ntpd           
udp6       0      0 fe80::3285:a9ff:fee:123 :::*                                3588/ntpd           
udp6       0      0 ::1:123                 :::*                                3588/ntpd           
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                                3588/ntpd           
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    34224    3588/ntpd
```

How it can listen port if ntpd disabled....

Comment: Why did you install ntpd? [By default chrony is the NTP daemon in RHEL 7](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Using_chrony.html) and it is probably already running.

Comment: You might check what's keeping port `123` busy using `lsof -i :123`

Comment: @Michael Hampton *which chrony*
/usr/bin/which: no chrony in ...
By 'default' in CentOS too small services...

Comment: Do an `# ss -tlpn` and show us the output.

PS: Use `ss` instead of `netstat`, netsat is now deprecated by Red Hat

Comment: @SergeySerov port `123` is being used by `httpd` so that port is already used. I thought you figured that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on information you provided (specifically the output of the first EDIT: "*netstat -lanp | grep ':123'*" and second EDIT: "*netstat -nlap | grep 'ntpd'*"), it's clear that:

- at the time of the first edit:

  - your system were running a process with PID  24483;
  - such process declared itself as named "ntpd";
  - such process bound to UDP port 123 for several IPv4 and IPv6 addresses;
- at the time of the second edit:

  - your system were running a process with PID  3588;
  - such process declared itself as named "ntpd";
  - such process bound to UDP port 123 for several IPv4 and IPv6 addresses;

Under normal conditions (like the ones I'm confident you're experiencing) this means that **you are already running an "ntpd" process**, and as one ntpd is already running, you cannot launch a new one (or, better, if you launch a new ntpd instance, it will refuse to start simply 'cause it will be unable to get control of needed resources (UDP port 123)).

So, as a general rule, before launching a new "ntpd", please ensure that no other instance is running (...by executing suggested ss/netstat commands and checking results).

As for your final comment -- "*How it can listen port if ntpd disabled*" -- please note that **running/not-running** and **enabled/disabled** are two very distinct concepts and:

- it's perfectly possible to have running processes that are **not** boot-enabled (...tipically 'cause you launched them manually, after the boot finished its initial running sequence);
- it's perfectly possible that a process/service, scheduled to be boot-enabled (and, as such, tipically lanched during the boot-sequence) is **not** running (...tipically 'cause you have manually stopped it after the boot or it stopped by itself for a plenty of reasons).

So, back to your (not-very-explicit) question:

- you're unable to launch ntpd 'cause it's already running;
- if you want to launch it again, please ensure to stop it before;
- if you want/don't_want it to be launched at boot-time, please ensure it's "enabled"/"disabled" (according to your distribution-specific approach);
- if you're having problems keeping your time "in-sync", please provide as much details as possible regarding your "ntpd" process (grep ntpd /var/log/messages , as a first start) and the firewall configuration you mentioned to have been applied/changed.

Comment: Thank You very much for Your detailed help!!
I research this problem deeper and find that one script in cron use *ntpd* command, and after it 'service ntpd status' failed and 'service ntpd start' fails too. Only after kill process it is became possible to run 'service ntpd start'.